# In my code for preorder traversal of binary tree, what is the reason for segmentation fault?

Tags: c++, vector, binary-tree, preorder

I have to return the elements of a binary tree in an int vector. I have written the following code, but it gives segmentation fault. What could be the reason for that? Also, does my code use correct logic?

```
struct Node
{    int data;
     struct *Node left;
     struct *Node right;
}
Node(int x)
{
     data = x;
     left = right = NULL;
}

vector <int> preorder(Node* root)
{
    vector <int> ans;
    if(root == NULL)
    {   
        return  {};
    }
    
    
    ans.push_back(root->data);
    ans.insert(ans.end(), preorder(root->left).begin(),preorder(root->left).end());
    ans.insert(ans.end(), preorder(root->right).begin(),preorder(root->right).end());
        
    
    return ans;

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling `preorder` twice for each `ans.insert`. They will return different vectors and their `begin()` and `end()` won't match. Therefore using them for specifying range is invalid.

Instead of this:

```
ans.insert(ans.end(), preorder(root->left).begin(),preorder(root->left).end());
ans.insert(ans.end(), preorder(root->right).begin(),preorder(root->right).end());
```

It should be:

```
vector<int> left_res = preorder(root->left);
ans.insert(ans.end(), left_res.begin(),left_res.end());
vector<int> right_res = preorder(root->right);
ans.insert(ans.end(), right_res.begin(),right_res.end());
```

Comment: Hey thanks for replying.!It works now.  So, calling preorder() separately accounts for two different function calls, therefore the references returned by the two calls would not match. Am I correct in understanding this?

Comment: `preorder` is returning a *value* not a *reference*